# Prove that for a general data structure - operations Extract_min() and Insert(x) cost $\Omega(\log n)$?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees

I've been given the following problem:

Given a data structure $M$ that is based on comparisons and supports the following methods on a group of numbers $S$:

- $\text{Insert}(x)$ – add $x$ to $S$
- $\text{Extract_min}()$ – remove the minimal element in $S$ and return it

We can implement with a heap the above methods in $O(\log n)$, however, we're looking at 
a bigger picture, a general case that we have no guarantee that $M$ is indeed a heap. Prove that 
no matter what kind of data structure $M$ is, that **at least one** of the methods that $M$ supports must take $\Omega(\log n )$.

**My solution:**

Each sorting algorithm that is based on comparisons must take at the worst case at least $\Omega(n\log n)$ – we'll prove that using a decision tree: if we look at any given algorithm that is based on comparisons, as a binary tree where each vertex is a *compare-method* between 2 elements:

- if the first is bigger than the second element – we'll go to the left child
- if the second is bigger than the first element – we'll go to the right child

At the end, we'll have $n!$ leaves that are the options for sorting the elements.

The height of the tree is $h$, then:

$$2^h \ge n! \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \log(2^h) >= \log(n!) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad h \ge \log(n!) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad h = \Omega(n \log n)$$

Then, if we have a $\Omega(n \log n)$ worst case for $n$ elements, then we have a $\Omega(\log n)$ for a single element.

I'm not sure regarding this solution, so I'd appreciate for corrections or anything else 
you can come up with.

Comment: What you wrote make sense. If both operations are "fast" then you would be able to use the database to sort $n$ elements in less than $O(n \log n)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: The title “Prove that exists a data structure that supports Extract_min() and Insert(x) in Ω(logn)?” does not match the question.

Comment: `Each algorithm that is based on comparisons must take at the worst case at least Ω(nlogn)`, this doesn't make sense, **Each algorithm** for doing what?for extract_min? inserting? what?

Comment: If those are the only two methods that need to be supported could they not both have constant time? Consider if M just tracks the current minimum. `Insert` compares to the minimum, and `Extract_min` returns it.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: And what about the second-smallest element? The runtime bound on `Extract_min` has to apply for that one, too.

Comment: @Raphael, I think you shouldn't add `sorting` in the `each algorithm`, actually even with this modification, OPs way is wrong (partially), it's better to let him/her to edit the question as the way he/she wants.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: The OP did not react to your comment for two days. I think it is pretty clear that sorting algorithms are meant here; note "... that are the options for sorting the elements."

Comment: Fair enough, I think he didn't checked this question in this two days (may be confused by migration and merge ;)

Comment: @Raphael, yes, I somehow overlooked the "remove" aspect.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think your proof is valid, because it only considers trees, and a certain type of trees at that. If there were an algorithm with a smaller lower bound for what you describe, we'd have a sorting algorithm faster than $\Omega(n \log n)$ no matter which of the two operations is $\log n$. So the problem reduces to proving that sorting cannot be faster than $\Omega(n \log n)$, which is a classical proof that you can find online.